# Grant CREATE TABLE permission only on database but not ALTER

Tags: sql-server, database-administration

Just trying to play around with permissions, I want to grant `CREATE` table permission to user but not `ALTER` or `DROP`. Moreover user should be able to create table only(no stored proc, no function)

```
grant alter on schema::dbo to demo_db_user
grant create table to demo_db_user
```

By using above command, user is able to alter table as well.

Comment: Do you want the user to be able to alter a table they've already created? or they can only alter the ones they've created?

Comment: I want this user to be able to create table but shouldn't alter any the table irrespective of user created including himself.

Comment: What if the user created the table incorrectly and it needs to be changed?  Do you allow them to drop it?

Comment: @MichaelMcGriff: I understand there are various concerns. However I am just playing on my local workstation to learn these things. So I didn't find a way to create table only without letting user alter it.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a DDL-Trigger and prevent the `ALTER TABLE` if the current User is not member in a specific role (or whatever), similar like this (untested):

```
CREATE TRIGGER [ddl_tr_prvent_alter_table] ON DATABASE
FOR alter_procedure
as
begin
  if User_Name() <> 'dbo'
    RAISERROR ('go ahead, you must not change a table', 16, 1);
end
```

Comment: You'd need a rollback in there as well, I think.